# Session ID from class into an other php file

Tags: php, class, session

I've got a class, in which i start a Session.
Now I would need the Session ID from this Session in an other file - my header.php file.

Im quite new to PHP, so I would appreciate any help.
Thanks a lot Rohan

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use the Session in other files, you can simply use it using the $_SESSION variable.

**A simple example:**:

```
test1.php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['Test_Value'] = "100"; //set session variable.
?>

test2.php
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["Test_Value"]; //get session variable.
?>
```

Now when you open test1.php and then open test2.php you will see output of 100 which was set from test1.php